# Why does C++ have such weird inheritance rules when using template base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
  class Xyz { /*...*/ };  // Type nested in class B<T>
  typedef int Pqr;        // Type nested in class B<T>
};

template<typename T>
class D : public B<T> {
public:
  void g()
  {
    Xyz x;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
    Pqr y;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
  }
};
```

The [result](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4abb558b37e1fe3e):

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void D<T>::g()':
main.cpp:13:5: error: 'Xyz' was not declared in this scope
   13 |     Xyz x;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
      |     ^~~
main.cpp:14:5: error: 'Pqr' was not declared in this scope
   14 |     Pqr y;  // Bad (even though some compilers erroneously (temporarily?) accept it)
      |     ^~~
```

Actually, I know why ([isocpp.org/wiki/faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-types)):

> This might hurt your head; better if you sit down.
>
> Within `D<T>::g()`, name `Xyz` and `Pqr` do not depend on template parameter `T`, so they are known as a *nondependent names*. On the other hand, `B<T>` is dependent on template parameter `T` so `B<T>` is called a *dependent name*.
>
> Here’s the **rule**: the compiler does not look in dependent base classes (like `B<T>`) when looking up nondependent names (like `Xyz` or `Pqr`). As a result, the compiler does not know they even exist let alone are types.

It really hurts my head. And what I'm asking is why do we have a so strange rule?

Comment: Suppose that you specialize `B` later and define `Xyz` as a variable.   Think of `Xyz* x;`. Is that a multiplication or pointer declaration?